# Is there an easy way to store/view changes made to a Django Database?

Tags: python, database, django

I've been looking around and solutions (that I can find) seem to deal mostly with general events (such as logging that a user logged into the system), or alike. Maybe my search skills have failed me, but I tried to research this and failed before asking.

**Looking for:** Due to the requirements of the software I'm creating, I need a log of changes made to the database and by which user.

So for example, if user `JjR2211` is the logged in user that adds a new entry to table `Item`, then I need to view something at a later point which would look like:

```
Entry Table
----
User        Change Made

JjR2211     Added entry to Item
...
```

Is there any built in functionality or available 3rd party libraries to achieve this, or is the only option to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Django-reversion](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/). I have the feeling it's exactly what you're looking for.